# No Space on CentOS with Docker

Tags: docker, centos, disk, device-mapper

I was using Docker on my CentOS machine for a while and had lot of images and containers (around 4GBs). My machine has 8GBs os storage and I kept getting an error from devicemapper whenever trying to remove a Docker container or Docker image with `docker rm` or `docker rmi`. The error was: `Error response from daemon: Driver devicemapper failed to remove root filesystem`. So I stopped the Docker service and tried restarting it, but that failed due to devicemapper. After that I uninstalled Docker and removed all images, containers, and volumes by running the following command: `rm -rf /var/lib/docker`. However, after running that it does not seem like any space was freed up:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  7.7G  346M  96% /
devtmpfs        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.8G  193M  1.6G  11% /run
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           361M     0  361M   0% /run/user/1000

$ du -ch -d 1 | sort -hr
3.6G    total
3.6G    .
1.7G    ./usr
903M    ./var
433M    ./home
228M    ./opt
193M    ./run
118M    ./boot
17M     ./etc
6.4M    ./tmp
4.0K    ./root
0       ./sys
0       ./srv
0       ./proc
0       ./mnt
0       ./media
0       ./dev
```

Why does df tell me I am using 7.7G whereas du tells me I am using 3.6G? The figure that du gives (3.6G) should be the correct one since I deleted everything in `/var/lib/docker`.

Comment: Cleaner to remove docker images with `docker rmi`. You may not have properly removed the images or the interim built containers.

Comment: I could not remove any containers or images with `docker rm` or `docker rmi`. I kept getting the error `Error response from daemon: Driver devicemapper failed to remove root filesystem`. Afterwards, I just uninstalled Docker altogether and deleted all images, containers, and volumes by running the following command: `rm -rf /var/lib/docker`.

Comment: Humm. Despite docker service being stopped some running processes (or something in kernel?) still using files under /var/lib/docker. `lsof |grep deleted` might have shown files in use? Killing off the processes would allow the files to be deleted.

Comment: Also use -x arg to du to get it to stay on one filesystem. `du -h -d 0 -x / |sort -h` as there may be more than one filesystem mounted in /.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. This [ticket](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21348#issuecomment-266111194) was helpful.

Depending on the file system you are using, you will want to use either `fstrim`, `zerofree` or add the drive to another machine or and use use `xfs_repair`

If your file system is xfs and you used `xfs_repair` then after running that command there should be a `lost+found` directory at the root of the drive that contains all the data that was taking upspace but unreachable.

You can then delete that and it will actually be reflected in `du`.